# how to ice restart?

Tags: android, webrtc, disconnect

I am developing a voice chatting `app` based on `webRTC` using android `libjingle`.I want to reconnect users by using ice restart when they change their network from `wifi` to 4g or vice versa, or are disconnected. I have a question about implementing it by using `libjingle`. I will write down how to implement ice restart function based on what I understood so let me know there is anything wrong.

Q: As I understand, at first I need to set ice start option to be true in the `MediaConstraints` option without removing peer connection 객체 used for the first connection like below:

```
mediaConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart", "true"));
```

Secondly, I need to update `MediaConstrants` using the peer connection 객체(used for the first connection)'s updateIce method like below:

```
peerConnection.updateIce(iceServers, mediaConstraints);
```

And finally is it right to send an offer, which is the same with basic `webrtc` network?

- I want to double check whether I understand well. And if there is something wrong in what I've written, please let me know!!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: yes i solve that

Comment: Awesome, could you share your solution? I still haven't figured it out and I  can't find any article for Android. Btw, are you using lib_jingle webrtc library?

Answer (score 7):

For doing ice restart, sender should send SDP file with different ice-pwd or ice-ufrag.
IceRestart option forces PeerConnection to update those values.

Steps should be:

1. Put additional constraint:

   `cons.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart", "true"));`
2. Generate sdp file:

   `pc.createOffer(new WebRtcObserver(callbacks), cons);`
3. Set resulted sdp to PeerConnection:

   `pc.setLocalDescription(new WebRtcObserver(callbacks), sdp);`
4. Send it to remote peer.

So steps 2-4 are the same as for regular offer.