# libjingle Android crash while restarting the video call

Tags: android, libjingle, webrtc-android

using libjingle for video call android. Usecase is Call should be reconnected when the network is reconnected.  So, what is happening is When the network lost and the peer connection state is disconnected and then went to a failure state. Getting crash while trying to reconnect again when network resumes. Here is below code used for reconnection.

```
 var iceRestartConstraint =
                            MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart", "true");
                        if (mRtcConstraint?.mandatory!!.contains(iceRestartConstraint)) {
                            mRtcConstraint?.mandatory!!.add(iceRestartConstraint);
                        }
                        mPeerConnection?.createOffer(sdpObserver, mRtcConstraint)
```

crash :

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 3630 (signaling_threa), pid 3541 (droid.ivvsample)

Can anybody tell me what the issue for a crash?

Note : following the below link
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450225/1954763

Or can anybody tell me how to reconnect the call if peer connection fails?

Comment: `fault addr 0x0` indicates a null pointer exception, which I believe it occurs because the connection is lost and either `mRtcConstraint` or `mPeerConnection` objects' native side releases the target memory, which you're trying to access again. Try re-creating those objects and then try resuming the connection to see if it helps.

Comment: The native stack trace should tell you something on which object throws the error.