# How can WebRTC reconnect to the same peer after internet disconnect?

Tags: java, android, socket.io, webrtc, turn

I am working on a peer-to-peer Video call system based on WebRTC in android.  my problem is I have no ideas how to reconnect video call when internet disconnect or switch from a network to other network (example switch from Wi-Fi to mobile)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do an ICE Restart. You do this by calling [restartIce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/restartIce) and then generating a new offer for web.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175624/how-to-ice-restart) for a specific android answer.

Comment: I do not use libjingle . I using from webrtc with below implementation:        implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'   .  i use from top code for restart ice  when connection state is disconnect  but reconnect done just for person 1 and just voice stream . video not stream